# Vertical space after title of unnumbered chapters (bibliography/ToC)

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, titlesec, starred-version

The title pretty much says it all: It is possible to add arbitrary vertical space after the title of the ToC or bibliography page within the `report` document class?

Comment: What document class? For most sectioning commands you can adjust them easily with the `titlesec` package.  See e.g. this question: [Formatting each part/section/subsection](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12517)

Comment: So sorry, I should have included that info.  I edited the question to include it!  Thanks for the info; I'll check it out.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Comment: @lockstep I haven't marked any of the answer choices because I haven't found a solution to the problem yet.  But I shall arbitrarily mark yours now.

Comment: You should update your question to explain why none of the answers given so far is satisfying. Also, it's okay to revoke acceptance of an answer if an even better answer comes along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* possible with `titlesec` to specify different formatting for numbered and unnumbered versions of sectioning commands: Use the `numberless` key within the first argument of `\titleformat` and/or `\titlespacing`. See p. 9 of the `titlesec` manual for details. (Note: For `\titlespacing` to work with `\chapter` or `\part`, you have to use `\titleformat` as well.)

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{200pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{1} A bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `sections` you either have to define `titleformat` first to use `titlepacing`

Answer (score 2):

The TOC and References use `\chapter*` in the `report` class. You can use the `titlesec` package to format `\chapter*` or `\section*` headings (see lockstep's answer) or you could simply modify the code from the class itself:

Add the following to your preamble, and adjust the spacing as you need:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}% space before the title
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@ % space after the title
  }}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I have to disagree -- it *is* possible to define specific formatting for the starred versions of sectioning commands with `titlesec`. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't aware of that option despite having used `titlesec` for years. I've edited my answer to be an alternative.