# chapter heading section heading

Tags: sectioning, fontsize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting each part/section/subsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12517/formatting-each-part-section-subsection)

I want to change the format of the chapter, section, subsection headings.

```
    chapter heading - all capital, 14 font size, bold
    section heading - Title case - 12 font size, bold
    sub-section heading - sentence case, 12 font size, bold
```

how can I do it?

Comment: Do any of the answers [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12517/14100) help out?

Comment: I would like to add that you shouldn't just change them arbitrarily and indenpendently, unless you have a very good reason to do it (possibly a styleguide for your university/publisher/conscience). In general you would want to set the fontsize for the main text via the `12pt`, `11pt` or `10pt` options to the documentclass and the rest will be adjusted in the correct way. Latex does it all for you.

Comment: @Max Do some people really consider font size a matter of conscience?!