# Article document class make subsection headings italic and remove boldface

Tags: fonts, sectioning, bold, italic, article

How can I make only the subsection headings italic and remove boldface in article document class ?

Comment: it depends to the document class. So you have to give a complete example

Comment: Welcome to tex.SX! A quick search for `subsection style` suggests that your question has already been asked before: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12517/formatting-each-part-section-subsection . Please have a look at that; it provides a fairly complete answer.

Comment: You can add `\usepackage{sectsty}\subsectionfont{\normalfont\itshape}` or `\usepackage{titlesec}\titleformat*{\subsection}{\itshape}` (as in the question linked by yori) in the preamble.